# Remove 0 in decimal places when using floor

Tags: sql, postgresql, decimal, floor

I'm using a select statement like below in my query:

```
FLOOR(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(16))/rate/100))
```

Even though I want my result to be like 123, the select statement above returns 123.0 instead. How do I remove "point zero" and display simply 123?

Comment: You can `CAST` the result to `INTEGER` or use `TO_CHAR` to format your number.

Comment: By the way: What data type is `amount`? Why must you cast it to `DECIMAL(16)` before applying `FLOOR`?

Comment: `amount` is string and I first need to cast it to decimal so that I can divide the amount by rate and 100

Comment: And it contains numbers with decimal places? Otherwise you could just cast to integer right away, thus do integer divisions and don't have to apply `FLOOR` at all.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, you want an integer result not necessarily integer division: `16/1/100 0`. Working backwards from OP's question something like: `select ('16'::numeric/.0013/100)::int 123`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky requirement, because essentially you want to display the numbers as floats, except when the decimal component be zero, in which case you want to display as an integer.  We can try casting to text, followed by a regex replacement.

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(
    FLOOR(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(16)) / rate / 100)::text,
    '\.0+$',
    ''
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I could come up with:

```
select ('16'::numeric/.0013/100)::int 
123
```